# Input icons in every input instead of amount of them

Tags: html, css

What should I change in my CSS to put every `i` icon to correct input box?
..
What the hell I should edit there when is already answered...

```css
.box_main {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box_main_content {
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    float: left;
}
.box_main_content_data {
    padding: 1em 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;

}
.inputWithIcon {
  position: relative;
}

.inputWithIcon i {
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
  padding: 19px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;

}

.inputWithIcon input:focus + i {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

input {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}


.lost_pass {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
            
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="box_main">
        <div class="box_main_content">
            <div class="box_title">
                <i class='material-icons'>login</i>Přihlášení
            </div>
            <div class="box_main_content_data inputWithIcon">
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Přihlašovací jméno nebo E-mail" required>
                        <i class='material-icons'>person</i>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Heslo" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" required>
                            <i class='material-icons'>lock</i>
                            <br>
                                <button name="btn_login">Přihlásit se</button>
                            </form>
                            <div class="lost_pass">
                                <button name="btn_login">Zapomenuté heslo?</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box_main_content">
                        <div class="box_title">
                            <i class='material-icons'>person_add</i>Regsitrace
                        </div>
                        <div class="box_main_content_data inputWithIcon">
                            <form method="post">
                                <input class="inputWithIcon" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Přihlašovací jméno" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" required>
                                    <i class='material-icons'>person</i>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Heslo" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" required>
                                        <i class='material-icons'>lock</i>
                                        <input type="password" name="password_repeat" placeholder="Heslo znovu" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" required>
                                            <i class='material-icons'>lock</i>
                                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                                                <i class='material-icons'>email</i>
                                                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Jméno">
                                                    <i class='material-icons'>badge</i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Příjmení">
                                                        <i class='material-icons'>badge</i>
                                                        <input type="date" name="age">
                                                            <i class='material-icons'>badge</i>
                                                            <label class="radio-checkbox">
                                                                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="0" checked>
                                                                    <i class='material-icons'>male</i>
                                                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                                </label>
                                                                <label class="radio-checkbox">
                                                                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1">
                                                                        <i class='material-icons'>female</i>
                                                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </form>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap every `input` with `div` and add `class="inputWithIcon"` to `div`'s:

```css
.box_main {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box_main_content {
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  float: left;
}
.box_title {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.box_main_content_data {
  padding: 1em 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.inputWithIcon {
  position: relative;
}
.inputWithIcon i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.inputWithIconLabel i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -2px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.inputWithIcon input:focus + i {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
input {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.lost_pass {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <div class="box_main">
    <div class="box_main_content inputWithIcon">
      <div class="box_title"><i class="material-icons">login</i>Přihlášení</div>
      <div class="box_main_content_data ">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Přihlašovací jméno nebo E-mail"
              required
            /><i class="material-icons">person</i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Heslo"
              onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)"
              required
            /><i class="material-icons">lock</i>
          </div>
          <br /><button name="btn_login">Přihlásit se</button>
        </form>
        <div class="lost_pass">
          <button name="btn_login">Zapomenuté heslo?</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box_main_content inputWithIcon">
      <div class="box_title">
        <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>Regsitrace
      </div>
      <div class="box_main_content_data ">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Přihlašovací jméno"
              onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)"
              required
            /><i class="material-icons">person</i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Heslo"
              onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)"
              required
            /><i class="material-icons">lock</i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password_repeat"
              placeholder="Heslo znovu"
              onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)"
              required
            /><i class="material-icons">lock</i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              class="inputWithIcon"
              type="text"
              name="email"
              placeholder="E-Mail"
              required
            /><i class="material-icons">email</i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstname"
              placeholder="Jméno"
            /><i class="material-icons">badge</i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Příjmení" /><i
              class="material-icons"
              >badge</i
            >
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIcon">
            <input class="inputWithIcon" type="date" name="age" /><i
              class="material-icons"
              >badge</i
            >
          </div>
          <div class="inputWithIconLabel">
          <label class="radio-checkbox inputWithIcon">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="0" checked /><i
              class="material-icons"
              >male</i
            >
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="radio-checkbox inputWithIcon">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1" />
            <i class="material-icons">female</i>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why I am banned when someone answered??

Comment: Hey mate, i don't know, maybe others didn't clearly understand your question :(